# Take multiple k samples of varying size n by groups in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, sample

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
group=rep(1:4,each=100)
values=round(runif(400,25,350),0)

data<-data.frame(values,group)
```

Each group is comprised by 100 observations (values).

For each group, I would take 20 random samples without replacement and varying sampling size starting from 10 and increasing by 5 up to 95.

Thus for each group I want 20 samples with size=10, 20 samples with size=15....20 samples with size=95.

Any idea on how to do it using some tidyverse solution?

At the moment I did this:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(v=map(data,~rep_sample_n(.,size=10,replace=FALSE,reps=20))) %>% 
  unnest(v)
```

It seems correctly replicate 20 times a sample with size=10, but still I need to change the size...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence of sample sizes, wrap your group_by/nest/etc dude into a For loop, then add each new sample to a list.

Notice how the size argument in `~rep_sample_n` is now `sizes[i]` rather than a fixed number.

```
sizes <- seq(10,95,by=5)

sample_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(sizes)){

  new_data <- data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(v=map(data,~rep_sample_n(.,size=sizes[i],replace=FALSE,reps=20))) %>% 
    unnest(v)
  
  sample_list[i] <- new_data

}
```

I am suggesting a `for` loop instead of `lapply()`, as it makes more sense to me and this application doesn't take much time anyway.

Comment: Thanks Kenmore, I've found a similar solution too, 'though I am struggling myself to try to combine map and map_df to do so to avoid loop...but still I haven't fixed it.